# Restore the state of std::cout after manipulating it

Tags: c++, iostream

Suppose I have a code like this:

```
void printHex(std::ostream& x){
    x<<std::hex<<123;
}
..
int main(){
    std::cout<<100; // prints 100 base 10
    printHex(std::cout); //prints 123 in hex
    std::cout<<73; //problem! prints 73 in hex..
}
```

My question is if there is any way to 'restore' the state of `cout` to its original one after returning from the function? (Somewhat like `std::boolalpha` and `std::noboolalpha`..) ?

Thanks.

Comment: I believe hex only lasts for the next shift out operation. The change is only persistent if you change the format flags manually instead of using manipulators.

Comment: @BillyONeal: No, using manipulators has the same effect as changing the format flags manually. :-P

Comment: If you are here due to a Covertiy finding ***Not restoring ostream format (STREAM_FORMAT_STATE)***, then see [Coverity finding: Not restoring ostream format (STREAM_FORMAT_STATE)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34503914).

Comment: I did something similar - see my question on Code Review: [*Use a standard stream, and restore its settings afterwards*](//codereview.stackexchange.com/q/189753).

Comment: This question is a perfect example of why iostream is not better than stdio. Just found two nasty bugs because of not-/semi-/fully-/what-not persistent iomanip.

Comment: For what it worth. Just found that std::setw affects only the next shift operation when compiled using g++ 4.9..0 with -std=c++11

Answer (score 133, accepted):

you need to `#include <iostream>` or `#include <ios>` then when required:

```
std::ios_base::fmtflags f( cout.flags() );

//Your code here...

cout.flags( f );
```

You can put these at the beginning and end of your function, or check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43771309/921224) on how to use this with [RAII](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321511/what-is-meant-by-resource-acquisition-is-initialization-raii).

Comment: Thanks! This is probably what I was looking for!

Comment: This didn't work for me.  I needed `const std::ostringstream default_format; ...; std::cout.copyfmt(default_format);`.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young, actually good C++ is RAII, especially in a case like this one!

Comment: @Alexis I 100% agree. See my answer (Boost IO Stream State Saver). :-)

Comment: THis is not exception-safe.

Comment: There's more to the stream state besides the flags.

Comment: You can avoid the problem by not pushing formats onto streams.  Push the format and data into a temporary stringstream variable, then print

Comment: Great that you linked the RAII answer[+] which answered the question I had *after* facing your helpful answer[+].

Comment: DO NOT RESTORE `std::setfill`

Answer (score 89):

Note that the answers presented here won't restore the full state of `std::cout`. For example, `std::setfill` will "stick" even after calling `.flags()`. A better solution is to use `.copyfmt`:

```
std::ios oldState(nullptr);
oldState.copyfmt(std::cout);

std::cout
    << std::hex
    << std::setw(8)
    << std::setfill('0')
    << 0xDECEA5ED
    << std::endl;

std::cout.copyfmt(oldState);

std::cout
    << std::setw(15)
    << std::left
    << "case closed"
    << std::endl;
```

Will print:

```
case closed
```

rather than:

```
case closed0000
```

Comment: Although my original question has been answered a few years back, this answer is a great addition. :-)

Comment: @UltraInstinct It appears to be a *better* solution, in which case, you can and probably should make it the accepted answer instead.

Comment: This for some reasons throws exception if exceptions are enabled for the stream. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2a4ce6f5d3d8925b

Comment: It seems that `std::ios` is always in **bad** state because it has `NULL` rdbuf. So setting a state with exceptions enabled causes exception throwing because of bad state. Solutions: 1) Use some class (for example `std::stringstream`) with `rdbuf` set instead of `std::ios`. 2) Save exceptions state separately to local variable and disable them before `state.copyfmt`, then restore exception from the variable (and do this again after restoring state from `oldState` which has exceptions disabled). 3) Set `rdbuf` to `std::ios` like this: `struct : std::streambuf {} sbuf; std::ios oldState(&sbuf);`

Answer (score 63):

The [Boost IO Stream State Saver](http://www.boost.org/libs/io/doc/ios_state.html) seems exactly what you need. :-)

Example based on your code snippet:

```
void printHex(std::ostream& x) {
    boost::io::ios_flags_saver ifs(x);
    x << std::hex << 123;
}
```

Comment: Note that there's no magic here, that `ios_flags_saver` basically just saves and sets the flags like in @StefanKendall's answer.

Comment: @einpoklum But it is exception-safe, unlike the other answer. ;-)

Comment: There's more to the stream state besides the flags.

Comment: @jww The IO Stream State Saver library has multiple classes, for saving different parts of the stream state, of which `ios_flags_saver` is just one.

Comment: Why for every small problem one should link against boost library...give me a break :D

Comment: If you think it's worth reimplementing and maintaining every little thing by yourself, instead of using a reviewed, well tested library ...

Comment: The link is now broken, here's the new address: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/io/doc/html/io.html

Answer (score 24):

I've created an RAII class using the example code from this answer. The big advantage to this technique comes if you have multiple return paths from a function that sets flags on an iostream. Whichever return path is used, the destructor will always be called and the flags will always get reset. There is no chance of forgetting to restore the flags when the function returns.

```
class IosFlagSaver {
public:
    explicit IosFlagSaver(std::ostream& _ios):
        ios(_ios),
        f(_ios.flags()) {
    }
    ~IosFlagSaver() {
        ios.flags(f);
    }

    IosFlagSaver(const IosFlagSaver &rhs) = delete;
    IosFlagSaver& operator= (const IosFlagSaver& rhs) = delete;

private:
    std::ostream& ios;
    std::ios::fmtflags f;
};
```

You would then use it by creating a local instance of IosFlagSaver whenever you wanted to save the current flag state. When this instance goes out of scope, the flag state will be restored.

```
void f(int i) {
    IosFlagSaver iosfs(std::cout);

    std::cout << i << " " << std::hex << i << " ";
    if (i < 100) {
        std::cout << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    std::cout << std::oct << i << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Excellent, if someone throws, you still got the correct flags in your stream.

Comment: There's more to the stream state besides the flags.

Comment: I really wish C++ allowed try/finally.  This is an excellent example where RAII works, but finally would have been simpler.

Comment: If your project is at least a bit sane, you have Boost and that comes with [state savers](https://www.boost.org/libs/io/doc/ios_state.html) for this purpose.

Answer (score 14):

You can create another wrapper around the stdout buffer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
int main() {
    int x = 76;
    std::ostream hexcout (std::cout.rdbuf());
    hexcout << std::hex;
    std::cout << x << "\n"; // still "76"
    hexcout << x << "\n";   // "4c"
}
```

In a function:

```
void print(std::ostream& os) {
    std::ostream copy (os.rdbuf());
    copy << std::hex;
    copy << 123;
}
```

Of course if performance is an issue this is a bit more expensive because it's copying the entire `ios` object (but not the buffer) including some stuff that you're paying for but unlikely to use such as the locale.

Otherwise I feel like if you're going to use `.flags()` it's better to be consistent and use `.setf()` as well rather than the `<<` syntax (pure question of style).

```
void print(std::ostream& os) {
    std::ios::fmtflags os_flags (os.flags());
    os.setf(std::ios::hex);
    os << 123;
    os.flags(os_flags);
}
```

As others have said you can put the above (and `.precision()` and `.fill()`, but typically not the locale and words-related stuff that is usually not going to be modified and is heavier) in a class for convenience and to make it exception-safe; the constructor should accept `std::ios&`.

Comment: Good point[+], but it of course remembers to using [`std::stringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) for the formatting part as [Mark Sherred pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273330/restore-the-state-of-stdcout-after-manipulating-it/43771309#comment84146603_2273352).

Comment: @Wolf I'm not sure I get your point. An `std::stringstream` _is_ an `std:ostream`, except using one introduces an extra intermediate buffer.

Comment: Of course both are valid approaches to formatting output, both introduce a stream object, the one you describe is new to me. I've to think about pros and cons now. However, an inspiring question with enlightening answers ... (I mean the stream copy variant)

Comment: You can't copy a stream, because copying buffers often doesn't make sense (e.g. stdout). However, you can have several stream objects for the same buffer, which is what this answer proposes to do. Whereas an `std:stringstream` will create its own independent `std:stringbuf` (an `std::streambuf` derivate), which then needs to be poured into `std::cout.rdbuf()`

Comment: @n.caillou "The" `std::ostream` instance is typically provided by the client (or is global, e.g. `std::cout`), and the client/global `ostream` state is what needs to be maintained/restored when returning.  The local/auto `std::stringstream` lets you isolate the state tweaks to a local `std::ostream` instead of manipulating the state of the client's `std::ostream` (or `cout`).

Comment: @franji1 again, you can do that without creating a stringbuf. you have not understood the answer; streams and buffers are separate things

Comment: Still a fantastic answer to learn from (and I've learned the lesson about “copying” streams). Those who are interested in the meaning of *rd* may read [*What does STL “rdbuf” method name stand for?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32770387/2932052)

Answer (score 10):

**C++20 `std::format` will be a superior alternative to save restore in most cases**

Once you can use it, you will e.g. be able to write hexadecimals simply as:

```
#include <format>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::cout << std::format("{:x} {:#x} {}\n", 16, 17, 18);
}
```

Expected output:

```
10 0x11 18
```

This will therefore completely overcome the madness of modifying `std::cout` state.

The existing `fmt` library implements it for before it gets official support: https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt Install on Ubuntu 22.04:

```
sudo apt install libfmt-dev
```

Modify source to replace:

- `<format>` with `<fmt/core.h>`
- `std::format` to `fmt::format`

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

#include <fmt/core.h>

int main() {
    std::cout << fmt::format("{:x} {:#x} {}\n", 16, 17, 18);
}
```

and compile and run with:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -o main.out main.cpp -lfmt
./main.out
```

Output:

```
10 0x11 18
```

Related: [std::string formatting like sprintf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342162/stdstring-formatting-like-sprintf/57286312#57286312)

Comment: Good to know, but as of almost April 2021, compilers don't support it, even though the standard is out there, maybe it's worth mentioning in this answer.

Comment: I am very much waiting for this library to become standard shipping with C++ compilers.

Comment: Meanwhile, the standard is out and also implementations that support it. The most impressing thing I experienced was that a **compile-time error indicates a mismatch** between format string and arguments.

Answer (score 9):

With a little bit of modification to make the output more readable :

```
void printHex(std::ostream& x) {
   ios::fmtflags f(x.flags());
   x << std::hex << 123 << "\n";
   x.flags(f);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << 100 << "\n"; // prints 100 base 10
    printHex(std::cout);      // prints 123 in hex
    std::cout << 73 << "\n";  // problem! prints 73 in hex..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of injecting format into cout, the `<<` way, adopting `setf` and `unsetf` could be a cleaner solution.

```
void printHex(std::ostream& x){
  x.setf(std::ios::hex, std::ios::basefield);
  x << 123;
  x.unsetf(std::ios::basefield);
}
```

the ios_base namespace works fine too

```
void printHex(std::ostream& x){
  x.setf(std::ios_base::hex, std::ios_base::basefield);
  x << 123;
  x.unsetf(std::ios_base::basefield);
}
```

Reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/setf/

Answer (score 0):

I would like to generalize the answer from qbert220 somewhat:

```
#include <ios>

class IoStreamFlagsRestorer
{
public:
    IoStreamFlagsRestorer(std::ios_base & ioStream)
        : ioStream_(ioStream)
        , flags_(ioStream_.flags())
    {
    }

    ~IoStreamFlagsRestorer()
    {
        ioStream_.flags(flags_);
    }

private:
    std::ios_base & ioStream_;
    std::ios_base::fmtflags const flags_;
};
```

This should work for input streams and others as well.

PS: I would have liked to make this simply a comment to above answer, stackoverflow however does not allow me to do so because of missing reputation. Thus make me clutter the answers here instead of a simple comment...