# Set back default floating point print precision in C++

Tags: c++, floating-point, default, precision, rounding

I want to control the precision for a double during a comparison, and then come back to default precision, with C++.

I intend to use `setPrecision()` to set precision. What is then syntax, if any, to set precision back to default?

I am doing something like this

```
std::setPrecision(math.log10(m_FTOL));
```

I do some stuff, and I would like to come back to default double comparison right afterwards.

I modified like this, and I still have some errors

```
std::streamsize prec = std::ios_base::precision();
std::setprecision(cmath::log10(m_FTOL));
```

with `cmath` false at compilation, and `std::ios_base` also false at compilation. Could you help?

Comment: Is your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/554134/1019491)?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can get the precision *before* you change it, with `std::ios_base::precision` and then use that to change it back later.

You can see this in action with:

```cpp
#include <ios>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main (void) {
    double pi = 3.141592653590;

    std::streamsize ss = std::cout.precision();
    std::cout << "Initial precision = " << ss << '\n';

    std::cout << "Value = " << pi << '\n';

    std::cout.precision (10);
    std::cout << "Longer value = " << pi << '\n';

    std::cout.precision (ss);
    std::cout << "Original value = " << pi << '\n';

    std::cout << "Longer and original value = "
        << std::setprecision(10) << pi << ' '
        << std::setprecision(ss) << pi << '\n';

    std::cout << "Original value = " << pi << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

which outputs:

```
Initial precision = 6
Value = 3.14159
Longer value = 3.141592654
Original value = 3.14159
Longer and original value = 3.141592654 3.14159
Original value = 3.14159
```

The code above shows two ways of setting the precision, first by calling `std::cout.precision (N)` and second by using a stream manipulator `std::setprecision(N)`.

---

But you need to keep in mind that the precision is for *outputting* values via streams, it does not directly affect comparisons of the values themselves with code like:

```cpp
if (val1 == val2) ...
```

In other words, even though the *output* may be `3.14159`, the value itself is still the full `3.141592653590` (subject to normal floating point limitations, of course).

If you want to do that, you'll need to check if it's close enough rather than equal, with code such as:

```cpp
if ((fabs (val1 - val2) < 0.0001) ...
```

Comment: Should this also work using setprecision() from <iomanip>? I tried it, and the precision doesn't seem to go back down to the original value after I increase it.

Comment: @Mike, that should work as well, as per my updated answer. Have a read over the changes and, if you still can't get it to work, you may want to open up a question here.

Comment: Is there any difference in how this would work if I'm pushing to ofstream rather than cout? I actually haven't tested it with cout---I'm writing to a file instead. Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: @Mike, no difference, should work exactly the same. In fact, I've just tested that. Replace `<iostream>` with `<fstream>`, do `std::ofstream ofs("output.txt", std::ofstream::out);` as first statement of `main`, do `ofs.close();` just before `return`, and change all `std::cout` into `ofs`. The `output.txt` file will then hold exactly what you saw on the screen with the code in the answer.

Comment: @Mike, try to do the same (with my code) on your system and, if you don't get the same results, post a question with your code. You'' get a much wider response that way.

Comment: Thank you, it's working for me now. I was forgetting to replace `std::cout` with the `ofstream` identifier. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @paxdiablo always Quality explanation as usual. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

**Use C++20 `std::format` and `{:.2}` instead of `std::setprecision`**

Finally, this will be the superior choice once you can use it:

```
#include <format>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::cout << std::format("{:.3} {:.4}\n", 3.1415, 3.1415);
}
```

Expected output:

```
3.14 3.145
```

This will therefore completely overcome the madness of modifying `std::cout` state.

The existing `fmt` library implements it for before it gets official support: https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt Install on Ubuntu 22.04:

```
sudo apt install libfmt-dev
```

Modify source to replace:

- `<format>` with `<fmt/core.h>`
- `std::format` to `fmt::format`

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

#include <fmt/core.h>

int main() {
    std::cout << fmt::format("{:.3} {:.4}\n", 3.1415, 3.1415);
}
```

and compile and run with:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -o main.out main.cpp -lfmt
./main.out
```

Output:

```
3.14 3.142
```

See also:

- [How do I print a double value with full precision using cout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554063/how-do-i-print-a-double-value-with-full-precision-using-cout/65266570#65266570)
- [std::string formatting like sprintf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342162/stdstring-formatting-like-sprintf/57286312#57286312)

**Pre C++20/`fmt::`: Save the entire state with `std::ios::copyfmt`**

You might also want to restore the entire previous state with [`std::ios::copyfmt`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/copyfmt) in these situations, as explained at: [Restore the state of std::cout after manipulating it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273330/restore-the-state-of-stdcout-after-manipulating-it)

main.cpp

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    constexpr float pi = 3.14159265359;
    constexpr float e  = 2.71828182846;

    // Sanity check default print.
    std::cout << "default" << std::endl;
    std::cout << pi << std::endl;
    std::cout << e  << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // Change precision format to scientific,
    // and restore default afterwards.
    std::cout << "modified" << std::endl;
    std::ios cout_state(nullptr);
    cout_state.copyfmt(std::cout);
    std::cout << std::setprecision(2);
    std::cout << std::scientific;
    std::cout << pi << std::endl;
    std::cout << e  << std::endl;
    std::cout.copyfmt(cout_state);
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // Check that cout state was restored.
    std::cout << "restored" << std::endl;
    std::cout << pi << std::endl;
    std::cout << e  << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/bf1ca6460da45526ea928fd20e53b3b4b2a22bf0/userland/cpp/copyfmt.cpp).

Compile and run:

```
g++ -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o main.out main.cpp
./main.out
```

Output:

```
default
3.14159
2.71828

modified
3.14e+00
2.72e+00

restored
3.14159
2.71828
```

Tested on Ubuntu 19.04, GCC 8.3.0.

Answer (score 5):

You need to keep track of your current precison and then reset back to the same once done with your operations with required modified precison. For this you can use **[std::ios_base::precision](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios_base/precision/)**:

```
streamsize precision ( ) const;
streamsize precision ( streamsize prec );
```

The first syntax returns the value of the current floating-point precision field for the stream.
The second syntax also sets it to a new value.

Answer (score 3):

setprecision() can be used only for output operations and cannot be used for comparisons

To compare floats say a and b , you have to do it explicitly like this:

```
  if( abs(a-b) < 1e-6) {   
  }
  else {
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `cout << setprecision(-1)`

Comment: Hm, it works but not documented.