# Coverity finding: Not restoring ostream format (STREAM_FORMAT_STATE)

Tags: c++, precision, coverity

We are catching a Coverity finding ***CID 156014: Not restoring ostream format (STREAM_FORMAT_STATE)*** (text below and image at the end).

```
 938        const std::streamsize oldp = cout.precision(6);
    5. format_changed: setf changes the format state of std::cout for category floatfield.
 939        const std::ios::fmtflags oldf = cout.setf(std::ios::fixed, std::ios::floatfield);
 940        cout << "  Maurer Randomness Test returned value " << mv << endl;
    6. format_changed: precision changes the format state of std::cout for category precision.
 941        cout.precision(oldp);
    7. format_restored: setf changes the format state of std::cout for category floatfield.
 942        cout.setf(oldf, std::ios::floatfield);
```

It appears line 941, `cout.precision(oldp)` is an issue. Coverity seems to classify it as a ***change*** rather than a ***restore***.

According to [set back default precision C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12560367/608639) on SO, I believe we are doing what is recommended. (But I could be wrong, or the accepted answer may not be a best practice).

How can we restore precision *and* squash the Coverity finding?

---

[image]

---

I recently tired the following, but it continues to produce the finding ***`format_changed: setf changes the format state of std::cout for category floatfield`***.

```
// Coverity finding
class StreamState
{
public:
    StreamState(std::ostream& out)
        : m_out(out), m_fmt(out.flags()), m_prec(out.precision())
    {
    }

    ~StreamState()
    {
        m_out.precision(m_prec);
        m_out.flags(m_fmt);
    }

private:
    std::ostream& m_out;
    std::ios_base::fmtflags m_fmt;
    std::streamsize m_prec;
};
...

StreamState ss(cout);
cout.setf(std::ios::fixed, std::ios::floatfield);
cout.precision(6);

cout << "  Maurer Randomness Test returned value " << mv << endl;
```

Answer (score 3):

After about 6 attempts (I think we used all of our submissions for the week), it appears we ***cannot*** use the member functions to set the `floatfield` in the program (i.e., ***`ostream.iosflags(...); ostream.precision(...)`***). We had to use the manipulators for the `floatfield` (i.e., ***`ostream << setiosflags(...) << setprecision(...)`***):

```
// Coverity finding
class StreamState
{
public:
    StreamState(std::ostream& out)
        : m_out(out), m_fmt(out.flags()), m_prec(out.precision())
    {
    }

    ~StreamState()
    {
        m_out.precision(m_prec);
        m_out.flags(m_fmt);
    }

private:
    std::ostream& m_out;
    std::ios_base::fmtflags m_fmt;
    std::streamsize m_prec;
};
```

And:

```
StreamState ss(cout);
cout << std::setiosflags(std::ios::fixed) << std::setprecision(6);
cout << "  Maurer Randomness Test returned value " << mv << endl;
```