# Why is scanf taking the wrong input for large float numbers?

Tags: c, gcc, floating-point, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() { 
float k;
    scanf("%f", &k);
    printf("%f", k);
}
```

In this simple program when I enter a number containing at most 8 digits then it is displayed correctly.

But if I exceed 8 digits i.e. for the input `123456789` the output is `123456792`.

Why this is happening? Well the fun fact is that if I enter any number between `123456789` and `123456796` then it always shows `123456792`.

Is it something related to the 8 decimal precision of floating numbers?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560291/set-back-default-precision-c

Comment: @HariomSingh How is that linked question related? It's not even in the same language.

Comment: @Toby question was originally double-tagged with [tag:c++], removed it because neither the code nor the text refers to C++.

Comment: read [Precision limits on integer values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#Precision_limits_on_integer_values)

Comment: ...and maybe you need `double` instead of `float`.

Comment: And this can also be of interest: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Chaitanya Vaishampayan: Curious what was your expectation of what values  `float` would have trouble? did you expect all possible numeric inputs to print out the same?

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Floating point types have a limited precision.  For a `float` on your machine, which appears to be 32 bit, it has 24 bits  of precision (23 explictly stored, 1 implied).  That means integers greater than ~16000000, which require more than 24 bits to store, can't be represented exactly with this datatype.

For example, the value 123456789 you used has a binary representation of:

```
111 0101 1011 1100 1101 0001 0101
```

This value takes up 27 bits which is more than is available.  So it is rounded to the closest value that can be stored with 23 bits, which is 123456792.  In binary:

```
111 0101 1011 1100 1101 0001 1000
```

For this value, the lower 3 bits with value 0 are not explicitly stored.

Comment: Off by 1: The ~16000000 is about right, but typical `float` has 24 bits of precision.  23 are directly encoded and 1 implied.  This first inexact conversion of an integer to `float` is with 16,777,217 (0x1000001), a 25-bit integer.

Comment: @chux Good catch.  Updated to reflect.