# [C++]: how do ostream cout and hex work?

Tags: c++

Here is my code:

```
void f(char c) {
std::cout << c << '\t'
    << (int)c << '\t'
    << std::hex << (int)c << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  f('a');
  f('b');
  f('c');
}
```

What I want is like: char intOfChar hexIntOfChar. But result is:

```
a   97  61
b   62  62
c   63  63
```

What I expect is:

```
a   97  61
b   98  62
c   99  63
```

I try to figure it out but fail. So how do ostream cout and hex work?

Comment: Use `std::dec` before `std::endl` to reset the stream

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273330/restore-the-state-of-stdcout-after-manipulating-it on saving and restoring the state of a stream.