# std::hex keeps the values not to change

Tags: c++, hex, decimal, std

I have some confusions in my codes regarding std:: functions.

```
cout<<tmp;
cout<<std::hex<<setw(4)<<tmp;
```

tmp is an int variable. After setting tmp to hex type, when I print tmp again, it is not converted back to decimal type (In face I have to include std::dec). Can anyone explain for me what happened behind-the-scene?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restore the state of std::cout after manipulating it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273330/restore-the-state-of-stdcout-after-manipulating-it)

Comment: are those two lines swapped? otherwise I dont understand what is the problem

Comment: The code does not "[set] tmp to hex type"; it sets the **output stream** to write numerical values by converting them to a hexadecimal text representation.

Answer (score 5):

`std::hex` is sticky. You'll need to use `std::dec` to change the settings so that subsequent integral numbers are displayed in decimal.

```
cout << std::hex << setw(4) << tmp;
cout << std::dec << setw(4) << tmp;
```

Comment: @MatteoRagni I was tempted to use "persistent".