# variable in c++ is changing in a function

Tags: c++

I have a simple converting function however the variable is changing.

```
void convert_print(std::string type,int num)
{
   if(type=="oct"){
       std::cout << num << " oct value is: " << std::oct << num << endl;
   }
   else if(type == "hex"){
      std::cout << num << " hex value is: " << std::hex << num << endl;
   }
}

int main()
{
   int num = 30;
   convert_print("hex",num);
   convert_print("oct",num);
}
```

Prints

```
30 hex value is: 1e 
1e value is: 30
```

Why is `num` getting changed to 1e when I call the function again.  I never reassigned `num`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't told `cout` to reset the formatting after your last call. This question describes how to restore it. [Restore the state of std::cout after manipulating it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273330/restore-the-state-of-stdcout-after-manipulating-it)

Comment: [`std::hex` is "Sticky"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532640/which-iomanip-manipulators-are-sticky)

Comment: Thank you I am getting back into c++.