# Equivalent of printf %g flag for stream output (e.g. for std::cout)?

Tags: c++, printf, iostream, cout

If I need to print a floating point number `x` I normally use `printf("%g", x)` as this is the simplest and the most convenient, for me, way to output floating point number in human-readable format where possible and automatically switch to exponential form for too large or too small values.

With `std::cout` and similar output streams it is not that simple. Say, I have class `point_2d` which overloads `operator<<` without changing stream's settings. E.g.:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const point_2d& p)
{
    os << '(' << p.x << "; " << p.y << ')';
    return os;
}
```

If I do

```
std::cout << point_2d_instance << std::endl;
```

the output will be in whatever format was set for `std::cout` by this point.

I cannot change `operator<<` implementation and I do not know the current state of `std::cout`. Which flags should I set in `std::cout` to get an equivalent of

```
printf("(%g; %g)", p.x, p.y);
```

Comment: `std::defaultfloat` to reset the formatting flag, or write to a string first instead of using `<<` on `os` directly.

Comment: As @user17732522 said, but since you said you must not modify the stream's current state, use a temporary copy of the stream's buffer and set `std::defaultfloat` only on the copy, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43771309/921224).

Comment: If you already use Boost, you can use [IO State Saver](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/boost/io/ios_state.hpp) to restore the state after whatever state changes you've temporarily made to the stream.  If you don't use Boost, probably a bit big to bring in for just this capability - but you could lift the code out of Boost just for this purpose.

Comment: To elaborate on @user17732522's comment, you can write to a `std::ostringstream` first with whatever formatting you want, and then write its final `std::string` to `os` when ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Equivalent of printf %g flag for stream output (e.g. for std::cout)?

`std::defaultfloat` or the default.

> the output will be in whatever format was set for std::cout by this point.

If you depend on a particular format when working with streams operator, you should store the flags set on the stream, set your own flags, then restore original flags.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ios>
using namespace std;
struct point_2d { double x; double y; };

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const point_2d& p) {
    std::ios::fmtflags oldflags(os.flags());
    os << std::defaultfloat << '(' << p.x << "; " << p.y << ')';
    os.flags(oldflags);
    return os;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << point_2d{0.1, 0.000000001} << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use [C++20 `std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) or the open-source [{fmt} library](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) which are not affected by the `std::ostream` state:

```cpp
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const point_2d& p) {
  return os << std::format("({}; {})", p.x, p.y);
}
```

This has an additional advantage of avoiding precision loss by default and you can control precision via format specifiers. You can also use the `g` specifier which has the same semantics as in `printf` except that it is not affected by the locale by default.

Or avoid `ostream` altogether and define a `formatter` specialization for your type which will make it work with both `std::format` and `std::ostream` (via `std::print`).

**Disclaimer**: I'm the author of {fmt} and C++20 `std::format`.