# Boolean to String and combining boolalpha with a method instead of having to type it separately when printing

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string STRING;

     bool isEqual(double a, double b)
    {
        return  fabs(a-b) ==0;
    }

int main()
{
   STRING = isEqual(3,3); <--------HERE'S THE MAIN PROBLEM

cout << STRING;


    return 0;
}
```

I'm having trouble setting the output I get from a boolean, be it "true" or "1" equal to a String.Also is it possible to use boolalpha and combine it with "isEqual()" 
so I can just type

```
cout <<isEqual(3,3) and it gives me "true" 
instead of having to type "cout << boolalpha<<isEqual(3,3) everytime".
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::string s = isEqual(3,3) ? "true" : "false";
```

also: you should in isEqual not compare with 0 but with a small value like `<0.00001`

Answer (score 1):

Since `isEqual()` is returning a `bool`, you should simply be able to use it in line with `boolalpha`:

```
cout << boolalpha << isEqual(3,3);
```

**Edit:** I see you edited your question to exclude the above option. The answers in the thread below still apply:

Also: [Converting bool to text in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29383/converting-bool-to-text-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

is it possible?  yes, if you can change the return type of your function to a wrapper that has an implicit conversion to either bool or string.

but it isn't a good idea.

c++ is strongly typed.  learn to make that work in your favor.

Answer (score 0):

You have a small problem in your code:

```
STRING = isEqual(3,3); <--------HERE'S THE MAIN PROBLEM
```

should be

```
STRING = isEqual(3,3); <--------THIS IS JUST WRONG, I'M TRYING TO ASSIGN A BOOLEAN TO A STRING
```

Why would you do this? I'm sure there are more elegant ways to do it. (presented in the answers). This is how I'd do it:

```
   bool areTheyEqual = isEqual(3,3);
   cout << boolalpha << areTheyEqual << endl;
```

or simply:

```
   cout << boolalpha << isEqual(3,3) << endl;
```

Comment: I know how to do it the way you described, I was just wondering if there was a way to do it without having to type cout<<boolalpha<<isEqual(3,3) everytime and instead just have to type cout<<isEqual(3,3) and then it either prints out true or false