# C++ send output of function to cout

Tags: c++

So I have a function called `isEmpty()` to check if a specified array has been filled with variables.

```
    bool isEmpty() const;
```

This is:

```
bool Array::isEmpty() const
{
   if(elemData == NULL)
        return true;
   else
        return false;
}
```

I'm trying to call it in my `main.cpp` so that I can send the output of `isEmpty` to `cout`, but I can't work out how to call it. I've tried a bunch of different methods but I feel I'm shooting in the dark, and I can't find any similar examples elsewhere.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean this?:

```
cout << array.isEmpty();
```

Booleans can be printed by default. In fact, every class you create can print out values
with cout, but only if you previously define both `ostream` and `istream` operators for this class.

Comment: foo.isEmpty(); gives me 'Expression must be a class type'. Is using Array foo(); wrong?

Comment: Don't forget you can have the boolean displayed as text: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29383/converting-bool-to-text-in-c/29571#29571

Comment: @JoeofLoath, That's a completely different problem. [Here's what Clang says with warnings.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/60eecbf4724a1400)

Comment: OK, how do I fix it? Or should I start a new question?

Comment: First create an Array foo and initialize it properly. Since this function returns a boolean value, it should let you print it out via cout. Give it another try and let me know the results

Comment: @JoeofLoath, See the link. The compiler says in plain English what to do.

Answer (score 3):

You can directly use

```
std::cout << your_container.isEmpty();
```

Or you can even output it like:

```
std::cout << std::boolalpha << your_container.isEmpty();
```