# Expression must have class type when using an array

Tags: c++, visual-c++-2010

I have a class for dealing with arrays and I am trying to check if it is empty. I keep getting the error "expression must have a class type."

This is my code:

```
int main ()
{
    Array ar1();
    bool isEmpty();
    cout << "The array is empty " << ar1.isEmpty();
}
```

What is wrong with it?

Comment: Seems like a classmate already had this problem. Look at the comments: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22712034/962089

Comment: What should `Array` be actually?? Looks like you have a function declaration!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to declare an array of Array elements write:

```
Array ar1[10];  // or other constant expression in [] as size specifier
```

This

```
Array ar1();
```

declares the function with name `ar1` taking `void` and returning `Array`. Function is not a class thus `"expression must have a class type"` error when writing `ar1.isEmpty()`.

Probably you want an array of some other elements then `Array` which is just mistake. This is how to declare an array named `array` of 10 `int`s:

```
int array[10];
```