# C++ isPrime function: How can I return a Boolean value from a function that takes an integer parameter?

Tags: c++, boolean, primes

I had to create a function that takes an integer parameter called number and the function would check to see if number is a prime number or not. Everything works but the output to the user would be a either 0 or 1, which is false and true, respectively. But how can I change that to instead return "True" or "False" if the number is prime or not, respectively.

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>

int isPrime(int);

int main()
{
  int number = 3;

  std::cout << isPrime(number);

  return 0;
}



int isPrime(int number)
{
  bool isPrime = true;

  if(number < 0)
    std::cout << "Number must be a positive integer.\n";

  else if(number == 0 || number == 1)
    isPrime = false;
  else
  {
    for(int divisor = 2; divisor <= number / 2; divisor++)
    {
      if(number % divisor == 0)
      {
        isPrime = false;
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  
  return isPrime;
}
```

Comment: Is this what you looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29383/converting-bool-to-text-in-c

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting bool to text in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29383/converting-bool-to-text-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your function should return a `bool` instead of an `int`:

```
bool isPrime(int number) ...
```

Next, you need to tell `cout` that you want to print boolean values as `true` or `false` instead of `1` or `0`. This can be done with [`std::boolalpha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/boolalpha):

```
std::cout << std::boolalpha << isPrime(number);
```

You have to `#include <ios>` for that.

### Edit

To answer some questions from the comments:

> What's the issue if the function is of type int and not bool?

The whole point of a type system is to express and restrict the behavior of a program. If you call a function you better know what you pass into that function and what that function returns. Types help you with that.

Take your `isPrime` function as an example. Let's say you didn't write that function but someone else did and you just use it as a library. You see the function signature `int isPrime(int);`. The function takes an `int` as an argument and you can probably guess what that argument has to be: the number that you want to check.

Now look at the return type `int`. What does this mean? The function name `isPrime` indicates that the function answers a simple yes/no question: is the given number a prime number? However, an `int` can represent more than just `yes` or `no`. For example, what does it mean if that function returns `2` or `-1000` (remember: you didn't write this function and you cannot look at its implementation)? Which value represents `yes` and which `no`? If you change the return type of that function to `bool`, a type that only has 2 possible values: `true` or `false`, you immediately get what the return value means.

> do I print that out in the main function

This is more of a design question and always depends on your very specific use case. Given only the code from the question: yes. You separated business logic, the part that does the prime check, from an IO / user interaction part. Generally, this makes code more readable and debuggable, two very important aspects of software development.

Comment: I always thought `std::boolalpha` is part of `<iomanip>`

Comment: @therealcain yeah I thought that as well. Only noticed it when linking to cppreference.

Comment: @Timo Thank you for pointing that out, I was looking around and I noticed that... But it still worked. What's the issue if the function is of type int and not bool? Also, do I print that out in the main function right?