# How do I reverse the effect of "cout << boolalpha" in c++?

Tags: c++

```
bool one = true;
bool two = false;
bool three = true;
bool four = false;

cout << boolalpha;
cout << "value of one : " << one << endl; 
cout << "value of two : " << two << endl;

cout << "value of three : " << three << endl;
cout << "value of four : " << four;

When I run this code, the values of `one` and `two` get printed out as `true` and `false`. I want the values of `three` and `four` to be printed as `1` and `0`, but they are printed out as `true` and `false` instead.

I'm new to C++ and can't figure out how to reverse the effect of the `boolalpha`.
```

Comment: Use `std::noboolalpha`?

Comment: `std::cout << std::noboolalpha`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/boolalpha

Comment: generic dupe but it doesn't have the better solution for this case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273330/restore-the-state-of-stdcout-after-manipulating-it

Comment: This one explains setting and resetting boolalpha: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29383/converting-bool-to-text-in-c

Comment: There is also Boost [IO State Saver](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/io/doc/html/io.html) which can be used to save the current stream flags state, then you can do whatever flag manipulation you need, and the restore the state.  (Don't have to use Boost to do this; could do it manually.  Boost just makes it convenient.)

Comment: If avoiding iostreams and sticky flags is an option, I'd use the [fmt](https://fmt.dev/latest/index.html) library: https://godbolt.org/z/oo8jdqs7x

Answer (score 5):

> How do I reverse the effect of "cout << boolalpha" in c++?

You can use `std::noboolalpha` as given on [std::boolalpha's documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/boolalpha):

> ```
> std::ios_base& noboolalpha( std::ios_base& str );   (2)
> ```
>
> 2. **Disables the boolalpha flag** in the stream `str` as if by calling `str.unsetf(std::ios_base::boolalpha)`

(emphasis mine)

This means you can write the following:

```
std::cout << std::noboolalpha;
std::cout << "value of three : " << three << std::endl;
std::cout << "value of four : " << four;
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/-Y48OFMyi)

Comment: I was commenting "What does this comment add to the already existing comment?" :P

Comment: @Enlico Haha ;)